# Close a dropdown completely before open another one

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick, navigation

I'm building a dropdown menu and need to add the following functionality to it:

When one dropdown is open and you open another one the previous one needs to close completely before the new one starts to open no matter how fast or slow the dropdown speed is set to.

**[Click to see DEMO](https://codepen.io/TiagoDeSousa/pen/jxYvvr)**

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
  var th = $(this);

  if (th.hasClass("active")) {
    th.removeClass("active");
   th.parent().find(".showup").slideUp(900);
   $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
  }else{
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(".showup").slideUp(900);
    $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
    setTimeout(function(){
    th.addClass("active");
    th.parent().find(".showup").slideDown(900);
$(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
    },250);

  }

});
$(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $(".active").parent().find(".showup").slideUp(900);
    $(".active").toggleClass("active");
    if ($(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
      $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have added code for both content (black box) and the hiding of the menu if clicked only outside the nav rather than showing on click of document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`.stop(clearQueue,jumpToEnd)`**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) along with the second parameter for the [**`slideUp()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and `slideDown()` i.e `complete` callback function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

you should first hide all open and then call the `slideDown` inside the complete callback of the `slideUp` so that once the opened menu is completely closed then the new drop-down should be opened.

Notice the 2 parameters passed to the `stop()` so that when you click simultaneously the animation should not keep on playing instead skips to the last state either shown or hidden

See a demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = $(this);
    toggleDropDown(menu);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    var container = $("nav");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        if ($('a.active').hasClass('active')) {
          $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function toggleDropDown(menu) {
  var isActive = $('a.active').length;
  $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
    if (menu.hasClass('active')) {
      menu.removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      menu.addClass('active');
      menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
      });
    }
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
      $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
    });
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #424242;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
  float: right;
}

.top-bar-section a.active {
  background: #c8c8c8;
  color: #000;
}

.showup {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

li.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.black-bg {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Comment: Looks good thanks.. However the other functionalities are missing such as the black box showing on click and the dropdowns close  when click outside

Comment: adding the line to add and remove class shouldn't be a problem but i have added them back the main problem was sliding panels after the animation is completed, i have edited @Tiago

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are any `.active`, if yes, `setTimeout()` with 900 miliseconds, if no, `setTimeout()` with 0 miliseconds(actually it would be [4 miliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Notes) but it would never 100% accurate).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var th = $(this);

    if (th.hasClass("active")) {
      th.removeClass("active");
      th.parent().find(".showup").slideUp(900);
      $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
    } else {
      let ms = $(".active").length>0 ? 900:0;
      $(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(".showup").slideUp(900);
      $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
      setTimeout(function() {
        th.addClass("active");
        th.parent().find(".showup").slideDown(900);
        $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
      }, ms);

    }

  });
  $(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });

});

$(document).on("click", function() {
  $(".active").parent().find(".showup").slideUp(900);
  $(".active").toggleClass("active");
  if ($(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
    $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #424242;
}

nav {
  /*width: 1024px;*/
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
  float: right;
}

.top-bar-section a.active {
  background: #f00;
}

.showup {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

li.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.black-bg {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```